# Group of homomorphisms with real target and circle target

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups

Denote by $\mathrm{Hom}$ continuous group homomorphisms. Fix the quotient homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$.

Can one characterize those topological (e.g., locally compact, and in particular discrete) groups $G$ such that the induced map $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})\to\mathrm{Hom}(G,S^1)$ is bijective?

Clearly this holds for $G$ if and only if it holds for the abelianization $G/\overline{[G,G]}$, so we can assume that $G$ is abelian and Hausdorff.

Comment: For any homomorphism from G to R, there are uncountably many scaled copies of it. This is not true for homomorphisms from G to S^1, is it?

Comment: @Anthony: check "Pontryagin duality". For instance for $G=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$, the group $Hom(G,\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})$ is infinite and countable (indeed cyclic).

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a simply-connected Lie group, then any Lie group morphism $G\rightarrow S^1$ factors through the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ to give a Lie group morphism $G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (by requiring the identity in $G$ to be sent to $0$). This gives a bijection between the Lie group $Hom$ sets. Is this the sort of answer you were seeking?

Comment: Well, there may be a lot more homomorphisms than the smooth ones, so this does not answer the question even in the setting of Lie groups...

Comment: Yes, that's certainly the case. For that reason, I indicated that the bijection existed only between Lie group Hom sets.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean *continuous* homomorphisms. Note that the condition only depends on the abelianization $G/\overline{[G,G]}$; let $H$ be its Pontryagin dual. By Pontryagin duality it's equivalent to determine for which LCA groups $H$ every element lies in a 1-parameter subgroup. These groups $H$ have been characterized by Dixmier (*): those of the form $\mathbf{R}^k\times D$ where $D$ is a discrete abelian group such that $\mathrm{Ext}^1_\mathbf{Z}(D,\mathbf{Z})=0$. This fully characterize groups with the required property.

(*) J. Dixmier. Quelques propriétés des groupes abéliens localement compacts. Bull. Sci. Math. (2) 81 (1957) 38-48.

Comment: Why do you assume continuous?

Comment: I think it is reasonable to assume continuity holds, at the very least. How often does one consider the groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$ outside of a topological context?

Comment: $\mathbf{R}$ as a discrete group is just $\mathbf{Q}^{(c)}$ (free $\mathbf{Q}$-module of continuum rank) and $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ is $\mathbf{Q}^{(c)}\times\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @IgorRivin insofar as we consider arbitrary topological groups, continuity is not a restriction but a generalization. If you want to consider arbitrary homomorphisms from a given topological group $G$ to the reals, then just change the topology of $G$. (On the other hand it would be a restriction if we were sticking, say, to separable topological groups, since this is not stable under the operation of changing to the discrete topology.)